# Kubuntu 19.10. Why no thumbnail preview?

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin, thumbnails, previews

I have thumbnails, but no previews on desktop and and none in dolphin. Via muon, all thumbnail related apps and libraries are installed. In dolphin, the preview button in menu does nothing. Can anybody find a solution?  Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` recently? Do both these commands run without any error messages or warnings? Also, please run `cd $HOME && find . ! -user $USER -ls`. The command will take a while to complete. Do you get many hits or do you just get back your terminal prompt?

Comment: Also, please clarify what you mean by "I have thumbnails". Can you add a screenshot showing where you see thumbnails and where you don't?

Comment: @ DK Bose.   Hi. Many thanks for reply. Excuse, I have been away. 1/ No errors or warnings for updates. 2/ The command "cd $HOME..." brings error " find: paths must precede expression: `=-user' "  3/ I have icons showing on desktop and dolphin. no preview.

Comment: `cd $HOME && find . ! -user $USER -ls` works for me. Please try again exactly as shown.

Comment: 4/ The original post is edited to show how the icons appear in dolphin and desktop. [excuse size. know not how to reduce].  -regards.

Comment: $ cd $HOME && find . ! -user $USER -ls     returns about 1000 lines all to do with thunderbird.  what should I search for?

Comment: I have several more questions. • Did you run `sudo apt full-upgrade`? • Is your install actually Kubuntu 19.10 or something to which you added KDE packages? • Are you sure the 1000+ lines with the `find` command are all to do with Thunderbird and **nothing** else? Such output represents files and folders owned by `root` and not by you. That is not good. • What is the output of `balooctl status`?

Comment: You can make images smaller using `Kolourpaint` which is present in a normal Kubuntu installation: Menu > Image > Resize > Smooth Scale and "Keep aspect ratio". Also, in a normal Kubuntu, there should be no need to install "thumbnail related apps and libraries". They are already there. Maybe you inadvertently uninstalled something. Running `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop` may help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103640/discussion-between-rob-grune-and-dk-bose).

Answer (score 1):

Out of frustration, re-installed Kubuntu, minimal manual. Problem solved. [no pain, no gain]. Thanks to all.